# Passing database name in mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, database, mybatis, ibatis

I need to pass the database name via a parameter in a hashmap.

My Mybatis XML is

```
<select id="getById" parameterType="hashmap" resultMap="result">
    SELECT * FROM #{db}.CONTACT WHERE CONTACT_NAME = #{name}
</select>
```

And my Java Call is

```
hm.put("db","abc");
hm.put("name","def");
Contact c=contactDAO.selectById(hm);
```

But I get the following error

```
The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your      
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax    
to   use near ''abc'.CONTACT WHERE CONTACT_NAME = 'def'' at line 1
```

Can we not pass database name as a parameter in mybatis ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `${}` instead of `#{}` for direct `String` substitution.

```
<select id="getById" parameterType="hashmap" resultMap="result">
    SELECT * FROM ${db}.CONTACT WHERE CONTACT_NAME = #{name}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked finally. The changes I made are

```
<select id="getById" parameterType="hashmap" resultMap="result">
SELECT * FROM ${db}.CONTACT WHERE CONTACT_NAME = #{name}
</select>
```

After a bit of study, the difference is that '#' is used for PreparedStatement substitution. '$' is for direct String substitution.

Answer (score 0):

As @yalpertem says (I can't add coments yet):

You need to use ${} instead of #{} for direct String substitution.

But a problem comes when the database starts with a number.
Usually this is resolved using "" on the db name.

```
 select * from "4dbname".tablename;
```

Or on MyBatis;

```
<select id="getById" parameterType="hashmap" resultMap="result">
    SELECT * FROM "${db}".CONTACT WHERE CONTACT_NAME = #{name}
</select>
```